# How to share VB project with another programmer overcoming the vbp "reference" issue?

Tags: vb6

I have this old VB6 project that is composed of a few DLLs, OCXs, and GUIs.

There is a GUI component that includes this in it's VBP file:

```
Type=Exe
Reference=*\G{00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}#2.0#0#C:\Windows\SysWOW64\stdole2.tlb#OLE Automation
Object={EAB22AC0-30C1-11CF-A7EB-0000C05BAE0B}#1.1#0; ieframe.dll
Object={3050F1C5-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B}#4.0#0; mshtml.tlb
Reference=*\G{64E54C86-D847-48F7-9AE5-D6C9B8E6A3A2}#3.0#0#..\..\bin\Crypt.dll#Crypt
Reference=*\G{B3E7F95C-B6D9-458E-B4D4-5272759B139A}#4.0#0#..\..\bin\SpeechMike.dll#SpeechMike_DLL
Object={831FDD16-0C5C-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}#2.1#0; MSCOMCTL.OCX
Object={AB4F6C60-4898-11D2-9692-204C4F4F5020}#29.0#0; Ccrpsld.ocx
Object={48E59290-9880-11CF-9754-00AA00C00908}#1.0#0; msinet.ocx
Object={9C526969-AA6E-4D61-BAFA-117FD20C2B38}#3.0#0; SpeechMike.ocx
```

The ***Reference*** settings are a pain since they always change from one machine to the other. I mean, the GUID '9C526969-AA6E-4D61-BAFA-117FD20C2B38', for the last one as an example, will be something on my system, but something else on somebody else's machine.

For now, to make it work, I erase References to Crypt.dll and SpeechMike.dll. Also Object SpeechMike.ocx. Otherwise, Visual studio looks for something that does not exists. Then in "project > references" I check both Crypt and SpeechMike and the ***Reference*** goes back to the VBP with the proper GUID and version. Finally, in 'project > components' I add the OCX and I'm good to go.

Am I wrong about that? How can I share the project with some else without going through hoops and loops to start the project?

I'm using MS Visual Basic 6 (part of VS 6 enterprise).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like "failure to maintain binary compatibility." Normally you only do this to yourself, but of course it can be a bigger headache if multiple people are compiling your libraries from the source Project files.

When you create ActiveX EXEs, DLLs and OCXs you need to create a "base" version where type and class ID values (GUIDs) get assigned.  The documentation even suggests that you do this leaving the procedures empty: just a comment line or something so the IDE does not remove the empty declarations.

You don't have to use an "empty" base reference library, it can be one with full code in it.

Once you have compiled this baseline library, you'd exit and save your Project.  Then rename this "empty" library as something else and from there keep it along with your Project source files.

After this you re-open the Project and go into Project Properties and on the Component tab change the Compatibility setting to Binary Compatibility and in the box there enter the full path and name of your compiled baseline library.  Save the Project.  Now you can add code and compile the "real" library to be used by other programs.

When you distribute these libraries (DLLs, OCXs) to somebody else in *source code form* so that they can compile them you must provide this renamed compiled baseline library along with the source code files, VBP file, resource files, etc.

From there your GUIDs will be stable until you make a change to something that breaks binary compatibility (changing a method's argument list, etc.).

There is more detail on this in the online Help (MSDN Library).  See:

[*Using Visual Basic|Component Tools Guide|Creating ActiveX Components|Debugging, Testing, and Deploying Components|Version Compatibility in ActiveX Components*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733715(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: +1 I would go so far as to say that nobody who is creating VB6 OCX and DLL components should be using anything other than binary compatibility in their project settings. This is VB COM 101 stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the endorsements of the answer and the rep.  This can be a difficult topic for somebody new coming to it for the first time, and there are few people who *grok* it in its entirety.  I know version trees as described in the docs still trip me up.

Comment: Thank you very for this greatly detailed answer, indeed I'm less then noob VB dev. and I was given this old project to resurrect and I needed to give to someone. But on opening the project I had a gazillion errors from each project. It took me quite a while to figure out. Now I will know what to store and share!